# Jmockit - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid place to record expectations

Tags: spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, jmockit

Jmockit 1.24 runs fine with my IDE(Intellij), but it is not with maven goals.

- Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can not attach to current VM
  This was my first error and I added 
  `<argLine>-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf</argLine>`
  to resolve that.
- java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit wasn't properly initialized; please ensure that jmockit precedes junit in the runtime classpath, or use @RunWith(JMockit.class)
  This was my next one and I added 
  `<argLine> -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.24/jmockit-1.24.jar</argLine>` to resolve that.
- Finally getting the below error and couldn't find a proper solution anywhere. 
  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid place to record expectations`

Can anyone who faced this issue help me with this. Looks like jmockit isn't initialized properly but not sure how to get around this error. My build is failing because of this.

Comment: Why are you running such an old version of JMockit?   Current version is 1.49.   Please provide your POM (so we can see the configuration) and the test (so we can see where your expectation is placed)

Comment: @JeffBennett indeed, ran in a similar issue an upgrading JMockit solved it